# Dual booting 16.04 and Window 10 with Raid 0

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, raid

I have a Fake RAID (ASRock Z77 extreme 4 MB Intel based raid 0.) I have windows installed on a Raid 0 drive consisting of four 120 GB SSDs. I would like to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 (UEFI). Having Windows reside on the SSD Raid 0 Volume and Ubuntu reside on a separate 1TB HDD (Non Raid Disk.) I also have a 2 TB storage drive that will share stored data between the two (Non RAID disk)

During the install process Ubuntu tells me "The computer has no currently detected operating system." If I choose the something else option I can choose the empty (1TB) drive that is available for the install of Ubuntu.

My worry is that Grub not seeing my windows OS will not set up the dual boot properly.

I have a little experience with Linux (enough to get me in trouble) so I don't want to just dive in without checking my facts first.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If installing in UEFI mode, it is vital that you have an ESP - efi system partition on the drive seen as sda, or grub will not correctly install. Is Ubuntu drive sda? If not may be easiest just to disconnect other drives. But UEFI NVRAM loses entries from other UEFI boot and those have to be recreated. Some UEFI find entries in ESP others need help using efibootmgr to create them. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mount point is / on the 1TB and make certain you pick that 1TB drive for your boot loader.  I can not tell you technically why this is happening to you, but I have experienced this before, not with Ubuntu though.  I just went on to use "F12" to enter my boot options every time I booted and selected WINDOWS BOOT MGR when I wanted Windows and LINUXDISTRO when I wanted Linux.

I know this doesn't answer your question, but that was my similar experience and work around.

Comment: That is perfect, thanks for the info. I will try it tomorrow and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to go through (as I've done at least ten times by now) is to first boot windows in safe mode, disable optane memory (if in use) and keeping windows in safe, boot to bios mode and change SATA connection from RAID to AHCI, and then boot in the bootable usb to install Ubuntu.
In my case, I was installing Ubuntu 20.04 and the usb installer doesn't let me install with raid configurations so I have to turn off raid before installing.

If the installer is letting you go upto the point of choosing something else,  then you must be free to go without any trouble.
Meanwhile installing grub on the drive the ubuntu is on won't give any troubles, even if windows is on same partition. It works perfectly.

Comment for more specific details.. Happy to help.